# Stop Airflow Backfill runs

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm using Airflow 1.9.0 Version.

DAG is running every minute. But when Airflow goes down for period of time or so we see lot of backfill job running which stopping recent DAG runs.

I'm using SubDagOperator.

```
dag_args = {
    'owner': 'Anish',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 20),#time in past
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(seconds=5),
    'email':Variable.get("failure_email_to"),
    'email_on_failure': False
}

dag = DAG(DAG_NAME, catchup=False, default_args=dag_args, schedule_interval="*/1 * * * *")

describe_table_by_fip_codes = SubDagOperator(
    task_id='process_flatten_sequences',
    subdag=subdag(DAG_NAME, 'process_flatten_sequences', dag_args),
    default_args=dag_args,
    dag=dag,
)


def subdag(parent_dag_name, child_dag_name, args):
    workerNumbers = 10
    next_subtask_interval = 10
    dag_subdag = DAG(
        dag_id='%s.%s' % (parent_dag_name, child_dag_name),
        default_args=args,
        schedule_interval='@once',
        catchup=False
    )

    for workerNumber in range(workerNumbers):
        sleep_time =  next_subtask_interval * workerNumber
        
        process_data = PythonOperator(
            task_id='{}_flatten_new_sequences_worker_{}'.format(child_dag_name, workerNumber),
            provide_context=True,
            python_callable=processSequences,
            default_args=args,
            op_kwargs={'sleep_time': sleep_time},
            dag=dag_subdag)

    return dag_subdag


def processSequences(sleep_time=0, **context):
    logger.info(f"sleeping for {sleep_time} seconds")
    sleep(sleep_time)
    #Start actual code execution logic after sleep


Airflow Configurations 
parallelism=64
dag_concurrency=64
celeryd_concurrency=64
max_active_runs_per_dag=32
non_pooled_task_slot_count=128
```

As you can see i'm using catchup=False and catchup_by_default=False in the airflow.cfg as well but still backfill task are coming up.

I'm nots sure if its issue with Airflow 1.9.0 version.
i went through articles and other post from stackoverflow but everyone suggesting same thing which i'm using already (catchup=False).

Any help will be appreciated.

thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Airflow will not backfill for the time period when it was down if catchup is set to False. Could be a bug in the version you are using.

One more option is to use [latest_only](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_modules/airflow/operators/latest_only_operator.html) operator which will skip the rest of the tasks if the DAG run is not the latest one. In this case the DAG runs will still get created but downstream tasks will get skipped.